# Polimorfismo en C++

Tags: c++

¿Que ventajas tiene usar la vinculación dinámica `objetoPtr->funcion();`sobre la vinculacion estatica `objeto.funcion();`?

¿Y por que es bueno declarar las funciones como virtual?

Comment: Estás confundiendo conceptos, la vinculación estática no tiene nada que ver con usar el operador punto (`.`) ni la vinculación dinámica sucede con la flecha (`->`).

Comment: Se que la vinculación dinámica se hace en tiempo de ejecución y la estática es en la compilación. Y el libro que leí decía que no podía haber polimorfismo si no había vinculación dinámica y que para eso se usaba el ->.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En C++ el polimorfismo no tiene nada que ver con la manera en que accedes a los miembros de un objeto (ya sea con el operador punto `.` o el operador flecha `->`). A grandes rasgos el [polimorfismo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) tendría algunos parecidos a la [polisemia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polisemia) del lenguaje oral/escrito.

Es decir, tenemos un objeto de tipo `Base` que según cómo haya sido inicializado se comportará como `Derivado_1` o `Derivado_2` de la misma manera que [la palabra "*capital*"](https://jackmoreno.com/2015/06/03/100-ejemplos-de-palabras-polisemicas/) (y otras polisémicas) pueden significar cosas diferentes según su contexto.

Respecto a si el polimorfismo es estático o dinámico, dejaré que este hombre responda:

[image]

> [**polymorphism** - providing a single interface to entities of different types. virtual functions provide dynamic (run-time) polymorphism through an interface provided by a base class. Overloaded functions and templates provide static (compile-time) polymorphism](http://www.stroustrup.com/glossary.html#Gpolymorphism).

Traducción:

> **polymorfismo** - proveer una interfaz única a entidades de diferentes tipos. Las funciones virtuales proporcionan polimorfismo dinámico (tiempo de ejecuión) a través de una inetrfaz proveída por una clase. Las funciones sobrecargadas y plantillas proporcionan polimorfismo estático (tiempo de compilación).

---

Una vez aclarado que el polimorfismo no tiene nada que ver con la manera en que se accede a los miembros de un objeto, vamos a ver los tipos de polimorfismo mencionados por [Bjarne](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup).

#### Polimorfismo estático.

Imagina que tenemos dos funciones con el mismo nombre pero diferentes parámetros:

```
void funcion(int)          { std::cout << "Entero\n"; }
void funcion(unsigned int) { std::cout << "Entero sin signo\n"; }
```

La función `función` sería polimórfica ya que tomaría *una forma diferente* según cómo sea llamada:

```
funcion(0123);    // Muestra "Entero"
funcion(0xcafeu); // Muestra "Entero sin signo"
```

Este efecto se da también con las plantillas, con la diferencia que escribimos el cuerpo de la función una sola vez y el compilador lo instancia por nosotros una vez por cada tipo<sup>1</sup>:

```
template <typename T>
void funcion(T) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCITON__ << '\n'; }

int main(int, char **argv)
{
    funcion(0b0000'0000'0010'1010);        // Muestra "void funcion(T) [with T = int]"
    funcion(u8"Tres tristes tigres");      // Muestra "void funcion(T) [with T = const char*]"
    funcion(L"Comían trigo en un trigal"); // Muestra "void funcion(T) [with T = const wchar_t*]"
    funcion(argv);                         // Muestra "void funcion(T) [with T = char**]"

    return 0;
}
```

Evidentemente, esto también es válido para funciones miembro:

```
struct S
{
   void f(float) { std::cout << "Flotante\n"; }
   void f(double) { std::cout << "Doble\n"; }
};

S s, *t = new C;
s.f(1.f);  // Muestra "Flotante"
s.f(2.);   // Muestra "Doble"
t->f(3.f); // Muestra "Flotante"
t->f(4.);  // Muestra "Doble"
```

Estos son ejemplos de polimorfismo estático, ya que la decisión de la *forma* que debe tomar la función se decide estáticamente (en tiempo de compilación).

#### Polimorfismo dinámico.

Imagina que tenemos tres objetos, derivando los dos últimos del primero:

```
struct Base                     { void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };
struct Derivado_1 : public Base { void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };
struct Derivado_2 : public Base { void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };
```

Al usar estos objetos tenemos el siguiente resultado<sup>1</sup>:

```
Base b;
Derivado_1 d1;
Derivado_2 d2;

b.f();  // Muestra "void Base::f()"
d1.f(); // Muestra "void Derivado_1::f()"
d2.f(); // Muestra "void Derivado_2::f()"
```

Si usamos un puntero a `Base` para referirnos a cualquiera de los objetos derivados tenemos el siguiente resultado<sup>1</sup>:

```
Base b;
Derivado_1 d1;
Derivado_2 d2;

Base *b1 = &d1, *b2 = &d2;

b1->f(); // Muestra "void Base::f()"
b2->f(); // Muestra "void Base::f()"
```

Pese a que los punteros `b1` y `b2` contienen objetos de tipo `Derivado_1` y `Derivado_2` respectivamente, se está llamando a la función `Base::f`; esto no debería sorprendernos ya que al fin y al cabo el tipo del puntero es `Base`; si queremos que sea llamada la función `f` de las derivadas debemos marcar la función `f` de la clase base como virtual (esto responde una de tus preguntas):

```
struct Base             { virtual void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };
//                        ^^^^^^^
struct Derivado_1 : public Base { void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };
struct Derivado_2 : public Base { void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };

Base b;
Derivado_1 d1;
Derivado_2 d2;

Base *b1 = &d1, *b2 = &d2, *pb = &b;

b1->f(); // Muestra "virtual void Derivado_1::f()"
b2->f(); // Muestra "virtual void Derivado_2::f()"
pb->f(); // Muestra "virtual void Base::f()"
```

Date cuenta que no ha sido necesario marcar como virtuales las funciones `f` de las derivadas para que estas sean consideradas como virtuales por el compilador... se han "*contagiado*" de la virtualidad al sobreescribir la función `f` de `Base` marcada como `virtual`.

Estos son ejemplos de polimorfismo dinámico, ya que la decisión de la *forma* que debe tomar la función se decide dinámicamente (en tiempo de ejecución).

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Hay muchas más cosas a saber del polimorfismo, como las funciones puramente virutales, polimorfismo estático de clases o el calificador `override`, pero dan para otras preguntas, te animo a que redactes nuevas preguntas sobre esos temas (después de haber investigado un poco por tu cuenta, claro).

---

<sup>1</sup>La salida está generada con GCC, otros compiladores podrían no disponer de `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.